# OS X sandboxing: difference between xattr and metadata

Tags: macos, filesystems, metadata, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

In order to do sandbox testing for an app I'm writing for OS X, I'm using `sandbox-exec`. I'm wondering what's the difference between the rules `(deny file-read-xattr)` and `(deny file-read-metadata)`?

Comment: If you're using Xcode and Cocoa for an NSApp, you're probably better off using an entitlements-file with com.apple.security.app-sandbox = YES and simply launch your App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- file-metadata is stored on a Filesystem-Level directly in the filenode: eg. last-modified-date
- xattr are filesystem agnostic and extendable: eg. com.apple.FinderInfo, com.apple.TextEncoding, com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms

Depending on which level you operate with files within your application (NSFileManager and NSURL or plain-old-c) you will probably need both read rules.

Comment: Hi, this is a good answer. My global daemon (EndpointSecurity client entitlements + Full Disk Access) emits tons of "Sandbox: MyDaemon(191) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-xattr /private/var/folders/....." I'd be very grateful if you clearly stated what I need to put into my entitlements file, and maybe a link that explains about these. Thanks!